# Fullcalendar full day overlap

Tags: fullcalendar, overlap

I'm using Fullcalendar for a vacation stay reservation system.  My problem is when a reservation is ending on a day and another one is starting that same day.

In Month view it shows both bars but one is above the other which makes the whole week taller.

What I would love to do is change the shape of the event bar in those cases to either be only half the day or better still to have a triangular shape on the end of each bar so it's clear that one event ends and the other one starts after the first ends.

In Agenda View there is a setting to let bars overlap (slotEventOverlap) but even that wouldn't work the way I want.  I am doing this for a client so I would like to be able to do what he asks but I can't find anything here that addresses this particular issue.

Edit: I'm using version 1.64 and in fact it's the Full Year version that is a fork from the original.  If there was a full year version of 2.x I would love to use that but I haven't seen any.